# C# - SQL Connection won't close

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm making a C#program that interacts with some SQL Server databases. The problem is if I connect to a database (dbA) and then close this connection and open another one to another database (dbB) and then do a Restore of dbA, the SqlException triggers saying that database (dbA) is in use. However if I execute the program and connect only to dbB, I can restore the other databases without problem, is like the first connection is kept stored. Anyway here is the code where the connection should open and close:

```
private bool CheckConnection()
    {
        bool res = false;
        string conString = string.Empty;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(serverBox.Text) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbBox.Text))
        {
            conString = ConcatConString(dbBox.Text);
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    res = true;
                }
            }
        }        
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: ADO.NET uses connection pooling, which means connections are "reset" and kept in a pool for reuse. You need to close the application or simply force all clients to disconnect before restoring

Comment: Please add full exception details with stack trace. Also, please share the code which is calling this method.

Comment: This isn't a major concern because restoring means that *all* users will lose whatever they were trying to save anyway. The best option is to put the database into SINGLE USER mode as [shown here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101917/unable-to-restore-database-backup-because-it-is-accessed-by-other-connection) which will rollback any active transactions, perform the restor then return the database to MULTI USER mode

Comment: @Rophit Dodle why? The problem is very clear. No need for a call stack or exception message.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't know of this problem before and thought it would help to know the stack trace. Your suggestions seem to be correct. Please ignore my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADO.NET uses connection pooling to reuse expensive connection objects. When you close a connection, any existing transactions are rolled back, its server-side state is reset and it's placed in the connection pool awating for the next `Open` command.

To the server though, that still counts as a server connection when you try to take such drastic actions as shutting down the server, restoring the database etc. That means that you have to take explicit action and tell the server that it's OK to proceed.

In this case, you need to set the database to SINGLE USER mode, perform the restore operation then bring it back to MULTI USER mode, eg:

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB] ...
ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET MULTI_USER
```

That's what SSMS does by the way, when you check the "Close Existing Connections to Database" option when restoring

You can also use `WITH ROLLBACK AFTER xx SECONDS` if you want give some time to existing connections to finish. In this case though, you are going to overwrite the database.

Comment: I think the `ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] SET MULTI_USER` may be unnecessary, when you restore the database I think it sets the database back to multi-user mode automatically.

Comment: That's the script SSMS generates when you check "Close Connections". Besides, it would be rather unpleasant if `RESTORE` changed the database mode behind the DBA's back, before he had a chance to verify data or proceed with differential backups. The [RESTORE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) command doesn't have any options that affect the connection mode

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely try that, seems like a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Closing a connection does not close it at the database, it just returns the connection to the pool maintained by ADO.Net. Normally I would never suggest this but it seems you may have a legitimate case for disabling connection pooling.

In the connection string set the `Pooling` attribute to `no` or `false` and the connection should actually close on the server.

You can observe how it works by running `sp_who2` in SSMS with connection pooling enabled or disabled in the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder bldr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        bldr.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        bldr.InitialCatalog = "YourDB";
        bldr.DataSource = "(localdb)\\YourServer";
        bldr.Pooling = false;  //Comment and uncomment this and run sp_who2

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(bldr.ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

> Update

Don't do this unless your program is the only thing connecting. I got the impression that the program was specifically for restoring databases. If you have other clients on the databases then this will tank performance.

Comment: There's no reason to disable pooling. Far easier to use SINGLE USER mode during restore.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question.